# Is it possible that P is a tautology but P[t'/x] is a contradiction?

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm studying 1st order logic (with identity) and proved that

lemma) If P is a formula and t' is a term and for any occurrences of variables of t' in P[t'/x] isn't bounded, then $$(\forall xP \rightarrow P[t'/x])$$ is a tautology.

After that, I wondered whether $$(\forall xP \rightarrow P[t'/x])$$ can be a contradiction.

**(The difference between lemma and this question is that it isn't required that the occurrence of a variable in t' can be bounded in P[t'/x])**

For making $(\forall xP \rightarrow P[t'/x])$ a contradiction, then $\forall xP$ should be a tautology(i.e. P is a tautology) and P[t'/x] should be a contradiction.

So, I tried to find a predicate formula P, term t', and variable x such that P is a tautology but P[t'/x] is a contradiction where P[t'/x] is a formula obtained by replacing all free occurrences of x in P by t'.

e.g.) P is a $~(\forall z x=y \rightarrow (\exists yR(y)->\exists x R(f(x, z))))$,
then P[z/y] is $~(\forall z x=z \rightarrow ( \exists yR(y) \rightarrow \exists x R(f(x, z))))$,
and P[g(w)/x] is  $~(\forall z g(w)=z \rightarrow (\exists yR(y) \rightarrow \exists x R(f(x, z))))$
where R is a 1-place relation symbol and f is a 2-place function symbol, g is a 1-place function symbol.

Some basic definitions of terminologies are common in many books, but some are not.

So, for being more specific, in my question, I will specify some definitions of

1. There are countably many variable symbols, function symbols, relation symbols. constant symbols in a Language.
2. For any variable symbol x and any formula P, $\exists xP$ and $\forall xP$ are also formulas and the for any variable in $\exists xP$ or $\forall xP$ and
   (the quantifier that binds the occurrence of the variable) is (the quantifier of the smallest subformula of $\exists xP$ or $\forall xP$ such that the occurrence of the variable is bounded.)

e.g.)$\exists z ~x=y$ is a formula.
$\forall y\exists x\exists y\forall x x=y \rightarrow R(x, y)$ means (semantically) there is a y such that for all x, x=y, then R(x, y) (And the occurrences of x and y in R(x, y) are not bounded by any quantifier).

I found some formula P and P[t'/x] such that P[t'/x] is a tautology and P isn't tautology.
(Also, P isn't a contradiction and P[t'/x] is a contradiction.)

---

P : $\exists z x=y$

P[z/y] : $\exists z x=z$   (tautology)

---

P : $\exists x\forall z$ ~x=y

P[z/y] : $\exists x\forall z$ ~x=z  (contradiction)

---

P : $(\forall z y=z \rightarrow \forall x x=y)$  (tautology)

P[z/y] : $(\forall z z=z \rightarrow \forall x x=z)$  (not tautology)

**(So, at least if P need not be a tautology, P[t'/x] can be a contradiction.**

**And it's possible that (P->P[t'/x]) isn't a tautology although P is a tautology.
)**

And the topic is equivalent to that "There is a formula P, term t', variable x such that P is a contradiction and P[t'/x] is a tautology."

So, Is it possible that P is a tautology but P[t'/x] is a contradiction?
If not, how can it be proved?

Comment: Please use mathjax to format your post.Cheack this [quick start guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Not clear... $∀xP \to P[t'/x])$ is a *valid* FO formula (a FO tautology). Thus, it **cannot** be a contradiction.

Comment: In my question, (∀xP→P[t′/x]) may not be a tautology. 

For example, if P is  ∀z (~z=y), then P[z/y] is ∀z(~z=z). 

And (P->P[z/y]) isn't a tautology.

Comment: I edited my post using mathjax.

Comment: $∃x∀z x=z$ is not a contradiction: in a domain with a single object the formula is true.

Comment: Oh, I took a mistake when I edited.

Comment: Actually it was ∃x∀z ~x=z, but in $\forall x\exists z ~x=z  $, ~ didn't show.  (I edited it to $\forall x \exists z$ ~x=z.) Thanks.